# How to highlight a selected row in ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I couldn't find something that will help me to solve this simple issue
in Angular. All the answers are relevant for navigation bars when a comparison
is being made against location path.

I've built a dynamic table using list and `ngRepeat`. When I click a row I'm trying to assign this row a css class, selected, to highlight the fact that this row has been selected by user, and remove the `.selected` from previously highlighted row.

I'm missing the method to bind between the row that been selected and the css class assignment.

I applied on each `row` (`ul`) `ng-click="setSelected()"`
But I'm missing the logic inside the `function` to apply the changes.

[My Code - Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gIeHOFdiDMoJcvBhxcCD?p=preview)

**My code:**

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);

//controllers
webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope, Votes) {
    $scope.votes  = Votes;
    $scope.statuses = ["Approved","Pending","Trash","Spam"];

    $scope.setSelected = function() {
       console.log("show");

    }
});

//services
webApp.factory('Votes', [function() {

    //temporary repository till integration with DB this will be translated into restful get query
    var votes = [
        {
            id: '1',
            created: 1381583344653,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 5,
            ip: '198.168.0.0',
            status: 'Pending',
        },
        {
            id: '111',
            created: 1381583344653,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '4',
            rate: 5,
            ip: '198.168.0.1',
            status: 'Spam'    

        },
        {
            id: '2',
            created: 1382387322693,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 1,
            ip: '198.168.0.2',
            status: 'Approved'

        },
        {

            id: '4',
            created: 1382387322693,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 1,
            ip: '198.168.0.3',
            status: 'Spam'
        }
    ];

    return votes;
}]);
```

**My HTML:**

```
  <body ng-controller='VotesCtrl'>
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li class="created">
            <a>CREATED</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            <b>IP ADDRESS</b>
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            <b>STATUS</b>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="setSelected()">
        <li  class="created">
          {{vote.created|date}}
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            {{vote.ip}}
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            {{vote.status}}
        </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   </body>
```

My CSS (Only selected class):

```
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Each row has an ID. All you have to do is to send this ID to the function `setSelected()`, store it (in `$scope.idSelectedVote` for instance), and then check for each row if the selected ID is the same as the current one. Here is a solution (see [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass) for `ngClass`, if needed):

```js
$scope.idSelectedVote = null;
$scope.setSelected = function (idSelectedVote) {
   $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
};
```

```xml
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="setSelected(vote.id)" ng-class="{selected: vote.id === idSelectedVote}">
    ...
</ul>
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkaYSbtKFdx1I9N0xP5E?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Well this solution IMO is better than the previous one.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using a controller? I am trying to find an 'optimal' way to do it in the view but I haven't had luck. I tried to do something like...   

ng-click="idSelectedVote = vote" ng-class="{selected:vote.id === idSelectedVote}" but upon clicking a row, other rows remain selected.  

Your solution works, but it would be nice if a view only solution existed.

Comment: @Spencer There's a new scope associated with each `<ul>` created by `ngRepeat`; therefore, `idSelectedVote` in your `ngClick` just modifies the local scope, and not the one shared with the others. Two solutions: use `$parent.idSelectedVote` instead (dirty, really!), or use an object (`ng-init="selectedVote = {id: null}"` in a `<ul>` ancestor) and only modify one of its properties, not the whole object (`ng-click="selectedVote.id = vote.id"`). Anyway, using the controller for that would **always** be a **far better solution**.

Comment: A custom directive could be the optimal way of moving the logic outside of the controller, depending on how complex your app is and how crowded the scope becomes.

Comment: @nikkwong Actually, that's usually a good idea to put the logic in the controller, unless your repeatedly use the same one, in which case a directive is well suited, indeed.

Comment: if you use it on a <tr> in a <table> don't use bootstrap class "table-striped" : http://jsbin.com/buloyoteqi/2/edit

Comment: @Blackhole Thanks for the soultion.Can you pls add a working fiddle

Comment: 1. you can use $rootscope if idSelectedVote is undefined when user come back to the table from other view or tab for example.                                   2. seriously you did not mention that you need:                                        .selected {
  background-color: red;
}

Comment: @dang 1) Apart from a few specific cases, it's generally a bad idea to use `$rootScope`. I'm not sure to understand why it would be useful here. 2) The CSS has already been included in the question by the OP.

Comment: @Blackhole Nice answer, have a gold badge with the 100th upvote. :)

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to have LI rather than the UL have the background-color:

```
.selected li {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Then you want to have a dynamic class for the UL:

```
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="setSelected()" class="{{selected}}">
```

Now you need to update the $scope.selected when clicking the row:

```
$scope.setSelected = function() {
   console.log("show", arguments, this);
   this.selected = 'selected';
}
```

and then un-select the previously highlighted row:

```
$scope.setSelected = function() {
   // console.log("show", arguments, this);
   if ($scope.lastSelected) {
     $scope.lastSelected.selected = '';
   }
   this.selected = 'selected';
   $scope.lastSelected = this;
}
```

Working solution:

[http://plnkr.co/edit/wq6nxc?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/3OjtzSUWdWCYTpXqxtOd?p=info)

Comment: I clicked up on this answer because I could get it to work and I couldn't get the checked one going. But you've got a couple of discrepancies between your code here and in your plunker. The ng-click above is missing the (this), and your class above has quotes around the property, but the plunker doesn't.

Comment: After I posted the Plunker link I noticed that it was missing quotes, and that the `this` in the argument list was only used by the console.log. However, you can pass in the selected row, or use this, but should not use $scope as that is the scope for the whole VoteCtrl: plnkr.co/edit/JoSUwA?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

I needed something similar, the ability to click on a set of icons to indicate a choice, or a text-based choice and have that update the model (2-way-binding) with the represented value and to also a way to indicate which was selected visually. I [created an AngularJS directive](http://jsfiddle.net/brandonmilleraz/5fr9V/) for it, since it needed to be flexible enough to handle any HTML element being clicked on to indicate a choice.

```
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ...>
    <li data-choice="selected" data-value="vote.id">...</li>
</ul>
```

Solution: 
http://jsfiddle.net/brandonmilleraz/5fr9V/

Comment: Please don't just link to external sites, blogs etc, even if you're the author - a good answer on stackoverflow contains the necessary details within the post itself.