# Highlight selected row in ng-repeat with logic only in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

This is a follow up question of [How to highlight a selected row in ngRepeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331779/how-to-highlight-a-selected-row-in-ngrepeat)

Here the row is being highlighted using a function defined in controller.I wanted to make the other way round,where I want to use only the code in HTML.
Below is my plunker that I have tried .
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZFKPokPN2TIc1bN6kzt?p=preview)
Pls share your thoughts on this issue:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" 
         ng-init="selectedRow = null"
          ng-class="{'selected':selectedRow == $index}" 
          ng-click="selectedRow=$index" ></tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5mZcDQkhDBYPEyAa13p7)

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" 
         ng-init="selectedRow = null"
          ng-class="{'selected':$parent.selectedRow == $index}" 
          ng-click="$parent.selectedRow=$index" >
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.value}}</td>
           <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(item)">Click</button></td>

</tr>
```

---

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $dialog) {

  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'foo', value: 'foo value',car:'chevy',model:'vette',year:'2013'},
    {name: 'bar', value: 'bar value'},
    {name: 'baz', value: 'baz value'}
  ];

 $scope.selected = -1;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is `ng-repeat` will create its own child scope each iteration which has its own `selectedRow` variable. That why when you click it activates the class but wont remove as the next row is setting a different instance of the `selectedRow` variable.

You can either refer to `selectedRow` with `$parent.selectedRow` or restructure your `$scope` to expose a property which you bind to. the latter gets around issue some people have reported with using `ng-model` directly of the scope.

```
$scope.model = {
    items: [],
    selectedRow: 0
}
```

Comment: I liked the way you explained it

Answer (score 1):

Please get the idea from below example:-

Use **ng-class-odd** and **ng-class-even**

> <ol ng-init="names=['John', 'Mary', 'Cate', 'Suz']">
>
> <li ng-repeat="name in names">
>
> <span ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
>
> {{name}}
>
> </span>
>
> </li>
>
> </ol>

Comment: ng-repeat can be used with any HTML for which developer want repeat it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle above condition using CSS, Please use the flovor of angularJS **ng-class-even** and **ng-class-odd**.

So while executing both will render but any one only will come into action.

Comment: well explaned, please add example or any plnk link with answers, it will make understandable.