# ng-repeat add and remove styling from div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an issue with `ng-repeat` and `ng-class` I have predefined data that i get from server where i run it trough `ng-repeat` and print them in `div` where I have a another `div` styled as button I would like to be able to set initial `div` say it `nth:child(3)` a specific styling that will highlight it from the rest but still be able to if button from other div is pressed to transfer that highlight to it. In short take the style from the highlighted div and transfer it to clicked.

I have managed to do this so far.

For sake of simplicity I will trim the code to bare necessities.

> view.html

```html
<div class="offer__container" ng-repeat="price in settingsPrices" ng-class="{'selected': price.selected}">
//Omited code
    <div class="offer__container__cta" ng-click="select(price)">Select
    </div>
</div>
```

> ViewCtrl.js

```js
//Omitted code

$scope.select = function(price) {
    price.selected = !price.selected;
}
```

> stlye.css

```css
//Omitted

.selected {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

At the current state `div` styled as button when clicked applies the change to parent `div` and on subsequent click it does take the style off. I now just need the way to make it unique so if say it first `div` is clicked it will have style but if 4th is clicked it should take off the style from first and apply it to 4th and so on...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331779/how-to-highlight-a-selected-row-in-ngrepeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat = "price in settingsPrices">

<div ng-class="$index == seletedDiv ?'selected':''" ngclick="select($index)">select {{price}}</div>

</div>

$scope.seletedDiv = 0;
$scope.select = function(index) {
  $scope.seletedDiv = index;
}

 Hope this works for u.
```