# Highlight single element in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

following problem:

I am using ng-repeat to generate a list of items. If the user clicks on a special marker on my webpage above, the following function receives an event an scrolls down to the corresponding item. In addition to scrolling down I would like to highlight the item until the user moves the mouse again. My problem ist that do to this I need to manipulate the css class of one single element of my ng-repeat list. I thought it might be possible because every ng-repeat element gets its own local scope...but I don't find the solution.

Part of my directive:

```
    //if a marker is clicked, the following code should bring the user to the corresponding item
    $rootScope.$on("Scroll_to_product", function (event, args) {
        product.gotoElement(args);
    });
    /*function which takes the class id of an html element as argument and brings
    the user to the corresponding product*/
    product.gotoElement = function (args) {
        var elementID = 'product-' + args;
        $location.hash(elementID);
        // call $anchorScroll()
        $anchorScroll();
    }
```

Any help would be great,

Thanks, Hucho

Comment: You can use `ng-class` in your template 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Here is a related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331779/how-to-highlight-a-selected-row-in-ngrepeat

Answer (score 0):

I think this woking Plunker example may help you

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkaYSbtKFdx1I9N0xP5E?p=preview)

```js
 $scope.idSelectedVote = null;
    $scope.setSelected = function(idSelectedVote) {
       $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
       console.log(idSelectedVote);
    }
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="setSelected(vote.id)" ng-class="{selected : vote.id === idSelectedVote}">
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

it almost broke my head, but finally was easy:

```
      product.highlightFeature = function (args) {
        var id = '#'+ 'feature-' + args;
        var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( id ) );
        myEl.addClass('feature-highlight');
    };
```

It is easy and fast..; yet thanks for your help.
This might help others...
Best

Hucho